# Geopackage no such table: main.gpkg_ogr_contents when deleting table contents

Tags: sql, geopackage, sqlite

I want to delete contents in several tables in geopackage using the following command

> DELETE FROM main.tablexyz

I’m able to delete some of my tables using this command but run into this error in a few others

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such table: main.gpkg_ogr_contents
At line 1:
DELETE FROM main.tablexyz
```

When I looked up main.gpkg_ogr_contents, tablexyz does exist in the field ‘table_name’.

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253045/sqlite-error-no-such-table-main-table-name-exists?rq=3) explaining the problem could have come from legacy SQLite versions.
The problem is, I don’t have a clear record on how this geopackage was created. What are the better options to clear contents in these tables?